Angular toSignal's read-only result as a writable signal
In my Angular service, I currently have a signal variable loginById$$ initialized from an observable:
public loginById$$: Signal = toSignal(this.getLoginById(), { initialValue: {} as LoginResponse });

Here is the getLoginById method implementation.
private getLoginById(): Observable<LoginResponse> {
    return toObservable(this._id$$).pipe(
      tap(() => this._isLoading.set(true)),
      switchMap((id) =>
        (id ? this.dataService.getLoginById(id) : of(null)).pipe(finalize(() => this._isLoading.set(false))),
      ),
    );
  }

Every change in the _id$$ signal triggers a new request. However, loginById$$ created via toSignal() is read-only, and I need to programmatically update this data at certain points.
I've considered the following solutions:

Use a separate Subject and merge its stream with getLoginById before
converting to a signal.
Create a writable signal with computed that wraps toSignal(...).
computed(() => signal(...))
Subscribe to getLoginById() manually in constructor and feed data into a writable
signal via .set()

Can someone help me to find a workaround that are best suited in this situation?

angular version?

@NarenMurali 18.2.9

Since the version is 18.2.9. You can just use a normal signal and initialize the observable stream on the constructor, the only difference is there is no auto un-subscription, which you can achieve using takeUntilDestroyed.
This emulates the linkedSignal of angular19 but we can achieve this easier with rxResource also from angular 19.
public loginById$$: WritableSignal<any> = signal({ initialValue: {} as LoginResponse }); // <- writable 

constructor() {
  this.getLoginById().pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(), // <- auto unsubscribe
  ).subscribe((response: any) => this.loginById$$.set(response));
}

private getLoginById(): Observable<LoginResponse> {
  return toObservable(this._id$$).pipe(
    tap(() => this._isLoading.set(true)),
    switchMap((id) =>
      (id ? this.dataService.getLoginById(id) : of(null)).pipe(finalize(() => this._isLoading.set(false))),
    ),
  );
}

